# Missing operator syntax

Tags: c#, ms-access, syntax, operator-keyword

I am getting a missing operator syntax error when doing this query against an access DB. It works when I use SQL server. Any help appreciated:

```
String sql = "Select tblStudent.StudentID,tblStudent.studentFirstName,tblStudent.studentLastName,tblSchool.schoolName,tblAgents.agentFirstName,tblAgents.agentLastName,tblAgents.agentID,tblGuardians.guardianFirstName,tblGuardians.guardianLastName,tblGuardians.guardianID,tblConsultants.consultantFirstName,tblConsultants.consultantLastName,tblConsultants.consultantID " +
        "FROM (tblStudent LEFT JOIN tblSchool " +
        "ON (tblStudent.schoolID = tblSchool.schoolID)) " +
        "LEFT JOIN tblAgents " +
        "ON (tblStudent.agentID = tblAgents.agentID) " +
         "LEFT JOIN tblGuardians " +
        "ON (tblStudent.guardianID = tblGuardians.guardianID) " +
         "LEFT JOIN tblConsultants " +
        "ON (tblStudent.consultantID = tblConsultants.consultantID) " +
        "WHERE tblStudent.StudentID=@studentID";

        m_dbConnection.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, m_dbConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", studentID);
            using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                      lblSchool.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["schoolName"]);
                      lblStudentFirstName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["studentFirstName"]);
                      lblStudentLastName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["studentLastName"]);
                      lblAgentFirstName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["agentFirstName"]);
                      lblAgentLastName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["agentLastName"]);
                      lblAgentID.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["agentID"]);
                      lblGuardianFirstName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["guardianFirstName"]);
                      lblGuardianLastName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["guardianLastName"]);
                      lblGuardianID.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["guardianID"]);
                      lblConsultantFirstName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["consultantFirstName"]);
                      lblConsultantLastName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["consultantLastName"]);
                      lblConsultantID.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["consultantID"]);
                      lblID.Text = studentID;
```

but if I do this: it works:

```
String sql2 = "Select tblStudent.StudentID,tblStudent.studentFirstName,tblStudent.studentLastName,tblSchool.schoolName,tblAgents.agentFirstName,tblAgents.agentLastName,tblAgents.agentID " +
        "FROM (tblStudent LEFT JOIN tblSchool " +
        "ON (tblStudent.schoolID = tblSchool.schoolID)) " +
        "LEFT JOIN tblAgents " +
        "ON (tblStudent.agentID = tblAgents.agentID) " +
        "WHERE tblStudent.StudentID=@studentID";
```

The answer was this. I had to use multiple parenthesis

```
  String sql = "Select tblStudent.StudentID,tblStudent.studentFirstName,tblStudent.studentLastName,tblSchool.schoolName,tblAgents.agentFirstName,tblAgents.agentLastName,tblAgents.agentID,tblGuardians.guardianFirstName,tblGuardians.guardianLastName,tblGuardians.guardianID,tblConsultants.consultantFirstName,tblConsultants.consultantLastName,tblConsultants.consultantID " +
        "FROM ((((tblStudent LEFT JOIN tblSchool " +
        "ON tblStudent.schoolID = tblSchool.schoolID) " +
        "LEFT JOIN tblAgents " +
        "ON tblStudent.agentID = tblAgents.agentID) " +
        "LEFT JOIN tblGuardians " +
        "ON tblStudent.guardianID = tblGuardians.guardianID) " +
        "LEFT JOIN tblConsultants " +
        "ON tblStudent.consultantID = tblConsultants.consultantID) " +
        "WHERE tblStudent.StudentID=@studentID";
```

Comment: which language? C#?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(tblStudent.agentID = tblAgents.agentID) LEFT JOIN tblGuardians ON (tblStudent.guardianID = tblGuardians.guardianID) LEFT JOIN tblConsultants ON (tblStudent.consultantID = tblConsultants.consultantID'.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.